# Trouble Reassigning NSArray values in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, for-loop, nsarray

I'm having trouble with a basic for loop in objective-c. I'm a little new to this language, but I'm trying to pull off the following:

```
for(int i=0; i<[yVals count]; i++)
{
    yVals[i] = exp(yVals[i]);
}
```

Where yVals is an array of doubles in NSArray.
However, I get this error in xCode: "Passing 'id' to parameter type 'double'".

How do I get around this? Am I oversimplifying things too much?

Comment: Beside the correct answer of @rmaddy, you should use fast enumeration instead of a for loop.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad An index is needed to do the assignment. If you use fast enumeration you need to add additional code to track the index.

Comment: @rmaddy Since the index runs from 0 to N-1, a new empty array and `-addObject` would do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to box/unbox primitive types. Your code needs to be something like:

```
for(int i=0; i<[yVals count]; i++)
{
    yVals[i] = @(exp([yVals[i] doubleValue]));
}
```

I'm assuming that `yVals` is an `NSMutableArray` of `NSNumber` objects.

Note the need to call `doubleValue` on the number so you can call `exp()` on it. Then the `@( )` syntax boxes the result back up into an `NSNumber` object so you can put it back in the array.

Comment: Thanks! How would I change this value if yVals is not a mutable array? Is it even possible?

Comment: What is `yVals`? If it's an `NSArray` then it is immutable and you can run your code. You will need to make a mutable copy of the array first.

Comment: Yes it's an NSArray. If I wanted to make a mutable copy, how would I go about that?

Comment: If you are going to be changing the array regularly, just declare it as an `NSMutableArray` instead of `NSArray` (and `alloc/init` an `NSMutableArray`). Otherwise you can call `mutableCopy` on your `NSArray` and assign it to an `NSMutableArray`. If you need more help, update your question with details about how you declare and initialize `yVals`. This will make it easier to point out what changes you need.